# How can I add sections in a Document Library?

Tags: web-part, list, content-editor-web-part, edition

I have a Document Library of uploaded documents which are classified in sections and displayed by a WebPart. I wan't to add a new section in this library but I didn't find where I can do that.
I must add that what I name "sections" is a column which permit "Group By" actions.

I tried to modify WebPart in web interface, nothing for sections.

There is anyway an upload button on the bottom of the page and I tried to put the name of a new section in the "Section" field but it upload the document and put it in any section.

[image: The "Category" column is highlighted]

*The "Category" column is highlighted*

[image: Column edit page]

*Column edit page*

I will be very pleased by your help.

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your category column is a choice column you should be able to update the categories by going to the list settings page, finding the column, and updating the available choices. You will not be able to do these steps through the web part. You have to have appropriate permissions to update the list itself, navigate the list, and go into the list settings page.

If its a lookup list column then you will have to locate the list that the categories are looking up to and add new items. In this case you don't need permissions to modify the list settings, just enough permissions to add new items to the lookup list.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
When I go in the document library settings and I look for the type of my columns I see that my column "Category" has the type "Search". And when I click on I can only edit the name, description and some ComboBox parameters but I have nothing to add a category. I hope you will understand me

Comment: Sounds like either a custom column type or a feature of SharePoint I haven't had to work with yet. Do you have a SharePoint administrator within your organization you can get more information on this column from? Or could you update your question a screen shot with that column settings page? Not sure how much I'll be able to help even with that though.

Comment: I will do that but I'm sorry, it's a french website

Comment: Thanks to Microsoft's website being multilingual I was able to determine that Recherche type column is a lookup column. If you click into the column it should tell you which list or library its coming from as well as which column in that list or library its coming from.

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry for the fogginess. Thank you a lot. I just see this section in column edit page, but this field "Obtain information from" (litteraly traduct) have the same value than the name of the column. I will also post an scrshot in my first post. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok so you can see that its getting data from "Rubriques SI" from the column "Rubriques" - if you go to Site Actions->View All Site Content you should be able to find the list or library "Rubriques SI" - go into that list and create a new item making the field "Rubriques" the category you want to appear.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works !! When I went to "View all site content", I didn't see any Rubriques SI list, buit this list was in the parent site ! Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to categorize your files and display them by that category in a web part (if I'm understanding you correctly). You could create a column with the category names, then set up views for those categories. In your web part you can choose which view to use. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It's not exactly what I want to do, my files are already categorized by a column, but I want to add a new category.

Comment: can you not add another category to your column? Then set up another view for this category?

Comment: No I didn't find how to add a new category in my column, I can only create new columns but I don't want to, in this case.